# Does Django support oracleDB nosql?

Tags: python, django, oracle, oracle-nosql

Im trying to use django with oracle nosql. I know django supports oracleDB but I don't know if oracle regular driver can be used by oracle nosql too. is there any driver for Nosql to support code first?

Answer (score 1):

Django supports Oracle Database Server versions 12.1 and higher. Version 5.2 or higher of the cx_Oracle Python driver is required.

Comment: Thanks, but I want work with Oracle nosql, does cx_Python support that?

Comment: I think the following link will help you
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/NOSQL/html/driver_table_python/GSGTablesPy/kvapi.html